# CPU spikes on Ubuntu using RunCloud / AWS Lightsail

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit

I am regularly getting alerts from my AWS Lightspeed server for high CPU usage.
The configuration is 2vpu, 4gb ram, 80gb ssd.
I use RunCloud for server management and have around 10 very low traffic WordPress sites.

I am running WordFence on all sites with the same settings, which I have dialed in as much as possible to lower resource use and harden security. Things like locking out after 3 attempts for 2 months, setting rate limiting for crawlers and humans, low resource scanning, traffic logging in security only mode.

I am also using RunCloud's plugin which provides NGINX cache, as well as Redis object cache, and CloudFlare enabled for all sites.

Occasionally MariaDB will crash, taking down all my sites. It hasn't done this since the latest tweaks to WordFence, but I can't be sure it won't happen.

When I run 'top' I can see occasional processes running anything up to 99% from php-fpm.
Some of the usage is from WordFence, but I also see a lot of the following:

Most of the time when I run (within a couple of seconds) s-trace p xxxxx
I will get
strace: attach: ptrace(PTRACE_SEIZE, xxxxx): No such process

When I do get a result I am seeing a lot of things like:
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1691575885, tv_usec=447551}, NULL) = 0 (many results)

accept(25, 0x7ffe63704c60, [112])       = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGQUIT {si_signo=SIGQUIT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=502, si_uid=0} ---
close(25)                               = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
munmap(0x7f0b4d8ca000, 65536)           = 0
....

I also see a lot of these type of messages:
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/runcloud/webapps/xxxx/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/vendor/composer/jetpack_autoload_classmap.php", 0x7ffe636fdc20, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
readlink("/home/runcloud/webapps/xxxxx/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/vendor/composer/jetpack_autoload_classmap.php", 0x7ffe63702de0, 4095) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Jetpack has been deactivated and deleted on this and all other apps, but WordFence seems to be constantly searching for it.

These processes are consuming a lot of resource and sending the server out of burstable zone very often.

Can anyone shed any light on what these mean and how to configure the server?

Since I am not a sysadmin at all, and merely trying to host some WordPress sites, I do ot know what any of this means, or what to look for. If someone can suggest whether I need to post the full output I can do so.

Comment: Do you mean **LiteSpeed** Web Server?

Comment: No, an instance of AWS Lightsail

Comment: You seem to have a dangling symlink `/home/runcloud/webapps/xxxxx/wp-content/plugins/wordfence/vendor/composer/jetpack_autoload_classmap.php`. You can remove this file but it has nothing to do with your performance issues. As well `strace` won't give you any insight in this case. You need to show your instances resources and your applications resource allocation.

Comment: this seems to have been cleaned up following the stopping and starting the server

Comment: Actually being able to show resources used by each application would be really helpful, but I dont know how to do that. Both AWS and RunCloud only show the server load as cpu use and burst capacity. Anything in particular I should be looking for in the web app config?

Comment: Please see comments requesting DB and OS additional information, following symcbean Answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> When I do get a result I am seeing a lot of things like: gettimeofday({tv_sec=1691575885, tv_usec=447551}, NULL) = 0 (many results)

Most likely this is being caused by an error detected in PHP. The default behaviour in Wordpress is to suppress reporting of errors - but on a typical Wordpress installation with plugins, each request can generate a LOT of errors. Note that PHP still *handles* the error - it just does not appear in any logs.

[Wordpress describes logging](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) as "DEBUG mode".

> Jetpack has been deactivated and deleted on this and all other apps, but WordFence seems to be constantly searching for it.

Are you sure it has been removed? Via the API? Including the directory? If you don't have [wpcli](https://wp-cli.org/) - get it and check.

> Occasionally MariaDB will crash

hmmmm. I've run several Wordpress installations (20-40) with moderate traffic volumes and never had mysql nor mariadb crash.

If you can't get an explanation from your logs after enabling them, you might want to take a look at xhprof or excimer.

Comment: This morning 5am the server went into sustained 60% cpu usage and became unresponsive. It wouldnt reboot from AWS Lightsail panel, and had to be stopped and restarted (I now have a static ip set up)

After stop/starting it stayed all day around 3% and then jumped to around 35% for 10 minutes.

I am currently trying to research debug logs on Local server, with all sites running the same php version, synced as closely as possible.

I have opened a ticket with the Woopayments plugin, which spawns jetpack-related cron jobs every 5m, and respawns after they are shut down in crontrol

Comment: If I check /var/log/syslog it will tell me such and such db table crashed, but I think this could just be the table that happened to be open when the server crashed

Comment: I also checked Monster insights (google analytics) traffic, and WordFence attacks.
Nothing excessive except one site with around 750 blocked attacks in 24h, in line with weekly and monthly averages

Comment: to clarify, jetpack has been completely deleted, no folder present

Comment: no errors with debug enabled on localhost, only a couple of warnings

Comment: Actually I get processor and memory usage per service in RunCloud, but only as a live view. I am attempting to install XHProf for PHP7 without breaking anything!

Comment: "hmmmm. I've run several Wordpress installations (20-40) with moderate traffic volumes and never had mysql nor mariadb crash." - Did they all have WordFence running.. the free version without control over scheduling?

Comment: Mostly the paid version, but a few free ones

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.